# Why is my array not initialising? Numpy - error

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am trying to initialize an array with another after making changes to it.

Using Numpy library function on python working on default pydataset

```
import numpy as np
from pydataset import data
iris_data=data('iris')
iris_arr=iris_data.values 

sp_l = iris_arr[:,0] #sepal.length
sp_w = iris_arr[:,1] #sepal.width

sp_l = np.array(sp_l)
sp_w = np.array(sp_w) 

if(sp_l.any() <= 5 and sp_w.any() <= 3):
   sp_le = np.asarray(sp_l)
   sp_we = np.asarray(sp_w)
```

NameError: name 'sp_le' is not defined

I expected sp_le to be initialized

Comment: you are using `sp_le` lower after this chunk of code?

Comment: what is the data behind `iris_data` ?

Comment: The data behind it is a bunch of numbers

Comment: yeah ok, but give us the sample for which you think `sp_l.any() <= 5 and sp_w.any() <= 3` this expression should evaluate to true

Comment: It won't be initialized if the condition is not `true`. Are you sure it is `true`?

Comment: (150, 5) - random numbers ranging from 1-5

Comment: Not ALL cases are true, some are and some are not

Comment: I thought that was the point of .any() function.

Comment: `iris_arr` is an array (verify that).  That means `iris_arr[:,0]` is also an array.  No further need to wrap it in `np.array...`.  What does `sp_l.any()` do?  Test it and show the value(s).  Does it make sense to compare that ('True') with 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem is the condition expression. The data you are using may not be able to pass the condition. So when you use the sp_le below, it is not initialized. If you could give out the value of sp_l and sp_w and check if it is good.And also as what hpaulj posted, if you want to tell if sp_l has elements smaller than 5, it is better to use (sp_l <=5).any()

Answer (score 0):

I can load the `iris` dataset from `sklearn` with:

```
In [317]: from sklearn.datasets import load_iris  
In [321]: arr = load_iris().data                                                
In [322]: arr.shape                                                             
Out[322]: (150, 4)
```

The result is 2d array; first 5 rows are:

```
In [323]: arr[:5,:]                                                             
Out[323]: 
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2]])
```

first and second columns are:

```
In [324]: sp_l = arr[:,0]                                                       
In [325]: sp_w = arr[:,1]                                                       
In [326]: sp_l.shape                                                            
Out[326]: (150,)
```

`sp_l.any()` just tests if any values are not 0.  I don't think you want that.

`sp_l<=5` tests if values of `sp_l` are less than or equal to 5

```
In [327]: (sp_l<=5).any()                                                       
Out[327]: True                # at least some are
In [328]: (sp_l<=5).sum()                                                       
Out[328]: 32                  # there are 32 true values in that test
In [329]: (sp_w<=3).sum()                                                       
Out[329]: 83                  # and 83 sp_w values are small enough.
```

It's unclear what you want, but one possibility is that you want the rows where `sp_l` is 5 or less and `sp_w` is 3 or less.

```
In [330]: (sp_l<=5)&(sp_w<=3)           # the () and & are important                                        
Out[330]: 
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, ... False])
In [331]: ((sp_l<=5)&(sp_w<=3)).sum()                                           
Out[331]: 12
```

We get the indices of those rows with `where`:

```
In [332]: idx =  np.where(((sp_l<=5)&(sp_w<=3)))                                
In [333]: idx                                                                   
Out[333]: (array([  1,   8,  12,  13,  25,  38,  41,  45,  57,  60,  93, 106]),)
```

and the actual rows:

```
In [334]: arr[idx[0]]                                                           
Out[334]: 
array([[4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.8, 3. , 1.4, 0.1],
       [4.3, 3. , 1.1, 0.1],
       [5. , 3. , 1.6, 0.2],
       [4.4, 3. , 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.5, 2.3, 1.3, 0.3],
       [4.8, 3. , 1.4, 0.3],
       [4.9, 2.4, 3.3, 1. ],
       [5. , 2. , 3.5, 1. ],
       [5. , 2.3, 3.3, 1. ],
       [4.9, 2.5, 4.5, 1.7]])
```